# Why are relational databases needed?

Tags: foreign-keys, relational-database, rdbms

Specifically thinking of web apps,

**(1) why are relationships(ie:foreign keys) in RDBMS even useful?**

The web apps I write have logic built-in that validates user input against required fields. I see no real use for foreign keys and thus no real use for relational databases.

Besides, if I were to put all the required field validation logic in the RDBMS(ie:MySQL) it would simply return a vague error. At least with PHP-based validation I know which field is missing and I can notify the user(though with Javascript-based validation this would almost NEVER happen anyway).

**(2) Was there a point in the past where RDBMS were useful for some reason or is there a reason they are useful now that I'm not aware of?**

I really need some insight on this topic. I'm simply can't come up with a good answer.

Comment: Many applications require persistent storage. RDBMS is one mechanism for storing related data sets. Other mechanisms can include flat files, XML, JSON, etc. If your app does not require persistent storage then perhaps RDBMS is unnecessary. Nonetheless, if you do need store data, it should always be validated on the client and the server before its saved in any persistent storage system (flat file, XML, JSON, RDBMS…).

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I see some key benefits to RDBMS, specifically cascading data integrity and practical data structure documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will come at this from a different angle.

I work at a place where we had a database that had no foreign key constraints, default values, or other data checks whatsoever in their initial records database.  The lead engineer's excuse for this was something similar to what you have described above.  "The application will ensure the referential integrity".

The problem is, we did not have a standard data layer (like an object relational mapping) over the top of the database.  We had multiple programmatic sources that fed into the same tables.  It was funny because after a while, you could tell which parts of the code created which rows in the table.  Sometimes the links lined up, sometimes they didn't.  Sometimes the links were NULL (when they shouldn't be), and sometimes they were 0.  We even had a few cyclic records which was fun.

My point is, you never know when you are going to need to write a quick script to batch import records, or write a new subsystem that references the same tables.  **It behooves us as programmers to program as defensively as possible**.  We can't assume that those who come after us will know as much (if anything) about how our schema should be used.

Comment: This is by far the best answer yet. I agree that RDBMS are a good way to have inline documentation. This is a real world scenario I can appreciate. You don't rely on the the relationships, but they are a 2nd source that clarifies the data's structure.

Comment: Defensive programming is just one answer. It also allows other views of your data - consider a simple webcart - with a fixed hierarchical schema you can see what orders match to what customer, what products appear on what orders but how do you get a simple view of your stock projections? Sales by product type?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not much of an SQL lover, but even I must say that the relational structure has its advantages.

It doesn't only allow validation. By providing the database with metadata describing the relations between the actual pieces information stored, a great number of optimizations are possible.

This makes it possible to quickly retrieve large, complex datasets. It also reduces the number of queries needed to make modifications and keep the data coherent, since most of the "book-keeping" is carried out automatically on the DB side of the connection.

Comment: Don't forget about [Referential Integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)

Comment: @Phil that's the term I was looking for when I wrote "keep the data coherent"! Thanks, I spent a while looking at the screen and for some reason couldn't come up with the words. "Some reason" could be lack of sleep and more code to write. Duh.

Comment: You make a nice point about complex data sets. Relationships do make it easier to perform complex queries as well as hints to ORM-based database drivers. Not sure who has the best answer, you or @jonfen.

Answer (score 1):

One incredibly useful feature of foreign keys in most relational databases are cascades.

Suppose you have a families table and a persons table. Each family can have multiple people, but a person can only belong in one family (one-to-many relationship). If you have foreign keys and you delete a family row, the database can automatically update all the related people, either by deleting them or setting their foreign keys to null.

If you do not have this constraint, you must handle this situation yourself, in your own code.

Comment: I see your point of view, but again if the app is built well then you shouldn't have to worry about this sort of cascading. I prefer to have my logic in one place rather than distributed among server-side scripts and the database.

Comment: @Brenden: Yes, if it is built well, then it will use foreign keys. :) You do not want to have this complexity in your own application. You can easily start dealing with very complex relationships (dozens of related tables) where you delete one row and a bunch of other rows across many tables also must be deleted. Once you write an application that requires this level complexity, cascades become invaluable.

Comment: So really, cascades can help ensure you don't have orphaned entries in a database. This makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: "If the app is built well" isn't the issue. "If the app is perfect" is getting closer. But "There's no such thing as *the* app" is closer still. In 30 years, I've never seen a database accessed by only one app for more than a few weeks. If the database is useful, there's always another app. Last Fortune 500 I worked in had apps written in more than 25 languages accessing their OLTP database. Some of those apps were first released in the 1970s.

Answer (score 1):

RDBMSs are still very useful. Not sure why you wouldn't think so. Foreign key constraints can be used to maintain referential integrity (in other words, to provide a simple way to express 1:1, 1:many and many:many relationships. RDBMSs are also useful because there was a rich theory accompanying practical developments, unlike previous DBMSs. In particular, relational calculus/algebra are nice since they allow for good query optimization, normalization, etc.

Not sure if that really answers your question. Wikipedia might list some advantages of RDBMSs.

Comment: What's the benefit of referential integrity other than protecting against "bad data"? If your app is built well you should never have data integrity issues, right?

Answer (score 1):

(1) why are relationships(ie:foreign keys) in RDBMS even useful?
First off, I think you are talking about foreign key CONSTRAINTS. Foreign keys are just a logical design feature that says that this entity matches up with that one.

The reason foreign key constraints are useful are:

- They help you adhere to the DRY (Don't repeat yourself) principle. Sure your app validates the relationship, but does it do it in several places? Are there multiple apps that access the same DB? Do you have to repeat the logic in each app? Hey, you could pull that logic out and use a common DLL for access to that data that enforces that logic.Better yet, what if that was built into the RDMBS so I didn't have to write custom code to do something so routine? Bam. Foreign key constraints.
- If your app enforces the foreign key validations, how do you force users who are working directly in the DB to honor your rules? I know, I know. You shouldn't let users into the back-end directly, but you just try telling that to the data analysts when they have a project for corporate and you are the bottleneck.

As to the vague error. Wouldn't your argument be better stated as RDBMS X has vague errors when data fails foreign key constraint checks? The way you have generalized it, you could also argue that we should use paper ledgers instead of computers because the constraint had a vague error.

(2) Was there a point in the past where RDBMS were useful for some reason or is there a reason they are useful now that I'm not aware of?
Yeah, that would be now, yesterday and probably long into the future.

I could go on forever about the reasons, but here is the big one...
It provides a common structured file format that is easy to extend, leverage by other applications. You may be too young to remember when every dang system had it's own proprietary structured file format, but it sucked. Plus, it forced you re-invent the wheel constantly in terms of things like indexing, a query language, locking, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> "I see no real use for foreign keys and thus no real use for
>   relational databases"

Judging by this remark, you seem to be underestimating what a relational database is for. Foreign key constraints aren't a defining feature of relational databases and certainly aren't the *only* reason for using such databases. The relational database model is a powerful and effective way to represent data and it remains so even if you decide you don't want to implement a foreign key constraint. I will therefore assume the question you really meant to ask is: Why are foreign keys useful in relational databases?

A foreign key constraint is just one kind of data integrity constraint. You can of course implement integrity rules outside the database but the DBMS is designed and optimised to do the job for you and is generally the most efficient place to do it because it is closest to the data structures. If you did it outside the database then you would have at least an extra round trip to retrieve the necessary data. You would also have to replicate the DBMS's locking/concurrency model in your application code.

The database optimiser can take advantage of constraints in the database to improve the performance of queries. It can't do that if the rules only exist in your application code.

If you have many applications sharing the same database then implementing data integrity rules in every application is impractical and expensive to maintain. Centralising the constraint logic makes more sense.

Various CASE tools and DBA tools will take advantage of database constraints, can reverse engineer them and use them to assist development and maintenance tasks.

In practice the meaning and function of a database constraint versus some procedural code that validates data only on entry is very different. If X is implemented in a database constraint then I know it is valid for every piece of data in the database. If X is implemented in the application when data is entered then I only know it applies to future data - I can't be sure it applies to everything already in the database (maybe X was only implemented today and didn't apply to the data entered yesterday).

Answer (score 0):

Because they maintain the integrity of the database. If you have all your business logic in the application then in theory they are not needed, but are still useful as a safeguard against bad data.

Comment: I'm all for redundancy, but is there an issue with having all the logic in the server-side scripts? Again, if your app is built well, you shouldn't have data integrity issues, right?

Comment: Right, that's why i said not needed in theory. I find that even when there are plans on having all logic in app some tends to creep into db anyway.